# Re-calculate start and end dates based on length of time elapsed between records (i.e., rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, window-functions, aggregation

I'm stumped. I have time series data in a SQL Server database.  Each row represents when a customer has stayed at the hotel. However, sometimes a customer will extend a stay, change rooms etc, which gets recorded in the system as a separate booking.  For our purposes, I need to consider those contiguous 'bookings' as a continued stay.  Consider the data:

```
| CUSTOMERID | STARTDATE  | ENDDATE  |
| --------   | -----------| -------- |
| 1          |2021-07-02  |2021-07-14|
| 1          |2021-07-19  |2021-07-27|
| 2          |2018-11-12  |2018-11-16|
| 2          |2018-11-17  |2018-11-19|
| 2          |2018-11-19  |2018-11-25|
| 2          |2019-01-10  |2019-01-15|
```

What I need to do is roll up any two records where the `STARTDATE` of the next visit for a customer is <=1 day difference from the `ENDDATE` of the current record.  In other words, there must be a full calendar day between visits to consider them distinct.  I need the final table to look something like this:

```
| CUSTOMERID | STARTDATE  | ENDDATE  |NEWSTARTDATE|NEWENDDATE|
| --------   | -----------| -------- |------------|----------|
| 1          |2021-07-02  |2021-07-14|2021-07-02  |2021-07-14|
| 1          |2021-07-19  |2021-07-27|2021-07-19  |2021-07-27|
| 2          |2018-11-12  |2018-11-16|2018-11-12  |2018-11-25|
| 2          |2018-11-17  |2018-11-19|2018-11-12  |2018-11-25|
| 2          |2018-11-19  |2018-11-25|2018-11-12  |2018-11-25|
| 2          |2019-01-10  |2019-01-15|2019-01-10  |2019-01-15|
```

Comment: Hi @lptr !  Thanks.  This is perfect.  A window function in a case statement in the sub query.  If you want to post the result to stackoverflow, I can mark it as the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @lptr for the answer, which includes a window function in a case statement of the subquery.  See link below:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2c905f2c31675c179d9f2100d74f44f

```
create table t(CUSTOMERID int, STARTDATE date, ENDDATE date);
insert into t(CUSTOMERID , STARTDATE , ENDDATE )
values
(1, '2021-07-02', '2021-07-14'),
(1, '2021-07-19', '2021-07-27'),
(2, '2018-11-12', '2018-11-16'),
(2, '2018-11-17', '2018-11-19'),
(2, '2018-11-19', '2018-11-25'),
(2, '2019-01-10', '2019-01-15');


select CUSTOMERID , STARTDATE , ENDDATE,
 max(sdate) over(partition by CUSTOMERID order by STARTDATE ) as NewStartDate,
 min(edate) over(partition by CUSTOMERID order by STARTDATE rows between current row and unbounded following) as NewEndDate
from
(
select *, 
 case when STARTDATE <= lag(dateadd(day, 1, ENDDATE)) over(partition by CUSTOMERID order by STARTDATE ) then null 
      else STARTDATE 
 end as sdate,
 case when ENDDATE>= lead(dateadd(day, -1, STARTDATE )) over(partition by CUSTOMERID order by STARTDATE ) then null 
      else ENDDATE
 end as edate
from t
) as t
order by STARTDATE ;
```